# ECS Service in hung state if desired count of container is greater than 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I'm creating a Cloudformation stack with ECS service. The stack completes creation if I mention [DesiredCount](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html#cfn-ecs-service-desiredcount) value as 1.

But when I increase the count to let's say 2 still I found that only one task is running.
The task runs normally with no error but the cloudformation gets stuck in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS state and after a while states that ECS service failed to stabilize. Probably, because it failed to spawn the remaining desired tasks.

What could be the reason for this sort of behaviour?

Comment: To help troubleshooting, you can go to the AWS console, ECS, click your cluster, then on the service tab, click your service name. Then, click the events tab, and you'll probably see something like "service <your service> has started N tasks: <task id> ...". Click those task IDs and you should have details about why (and if) they failed.

Comment: @Viccari you're solution helped me finally find an error message that got me on my way. You should have made your comment as an answer so it could be accepted. Ah well, I upvoted your comment.

Comment: @DanielPaulSearles I'm actually gonna add an answer, good idea.

Answer (score 5):

To help troubleshooting, you can go to the AWS console, ECS, click your cluster, then on the service tab, click your service name. Then, click the events tab, and you'll probably see something like:

> service [your service] has started N tasks: [task id] ...

Click those task IDs and you should have details about why (and if) they failed.

Comment: This helped me find the issue. My tasks were restarting over and over due to errors that I couldn't see in Cloudformation. Thank you for your help.